# Hosting subdomain with digital ocean and bluehost

Tags: node.js, dns

My domain is on bluehost but my backend is on digital ocean. I need to assign admin.mydomain.com to 12.12.122.1:3000 lets say.

what should I do and is there any other way ?

Comment: Tell us some details about your backend technology and what you have tried so far.

Comment: My backend is build with node js and I can't host it on bluehost. What I tried is to redirect but this is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

Add the domain to your Digital Ocean account first then install `nginx` on your server.

And use `nginx` to forward your requests to node:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass 12.12.122.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: its a client website and he use bluehost i dont think he might want to migrate